# Copy Time Machine network backup (SMB) to USB dirve

Tags: time-machine

I have Time Machine backup on SMB dirve (Synology). Now in order to restore it faster I would like to copy this backup into USB drive.

I've created GUID Partition and copied there folder MyBackuo.backupbundle.

Now when I boot into recovery mode and select "Restore from Time Machine Backup" it does not show my usb drive.

I can see this drive in /Volumes (from terminal)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem..... I've created backup on latest OSX version and the computer where I wanted to restore it had older version. After updating to latest version all works fine.